# What does the type ((Int) -> Int) mean in Swift?

Tags: types, swift

I was going through Apple's introduction to Swift and came across such example:

```
func makeIncrementer() -> ((Int) -> Int) {

    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne

}
var increment = makeIncrementer()
increment(7)
```

Can you please explain the syntax of the return type of the makeIncrementer function? I understand that this function returns another function, but there role of `((Int) -> Int)` in this context is still unclear for me.

Comment: (Being a return type is not immediately relevant, although it does bring up an interesting example: it could also have been a type of a variable, eg.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It indicates that the function returns a **function** and that returned function  takes an `Int` as an input parameter and returns an `Int` as well.

Defining functions within functions is perfectly legal in Swift.

Answer (score 2):

`(Int -> Int)` denotes a closure (or function) taking an `Int` as parameter and returning an `Int`.

The syntax for declaring a closure type is:

```
(parameters) -> (return_types)
```

`parameters` is a list of parameters the closure receives as input, and `return_types` is the list of values the closure returns. Both are tuples, but in case of one parameter or one return type, the parenthesis identifying the tuple can be omitted. So for example a clousure expecting one parameter and returning one value can be defined as:

```
parameter -> return_type
```

In your case:

```
Int -> Int
```

is a closure having 1 input parameter of `Int` type and returning a `Int`

The return type is enclosed in parenthesis to make it clear that's the return type, but you could also write it as:

```
func makeIncrementer() -> Int -> Int {
```

Which is in my opinion less readable than

```
func makeIncrementer() -> (Int -> Int) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly familiar with the syntax of swift, but I guess all higher-order functions work the same. `makeIncrementer` is a function that:

- takes **no** parameters
- returns a function that:

  - takes an `Int` parameter
  - returns an `Int`

Visual explanation (`a -> b` means a function that takes type `a` as the parameter and returns type `b`):

```
 makeIncrementer -> (Int -> Int)
                           ^
                           |
                           |
                           a function that takes an Int and returns an Int,
                           i.e. (addOne in your case)
```